# Popen not returning what I expect from `find` call

Tags: python, subprocess

I have been using

```sh
find /path/to/dir/ -name "*.csv" > sometextfile.txt
```

to find a bunch of files on a network drive, and store them in a text file. This takes a couple hours. Later, I would read in all the lines (a few million) in python and process each file.

I would like to do this more quickly, ideally by running `find` from python and processing the files as they are found.

A basic python script of what I have so far is

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen("find . -name '*.csv'".split(), stdout=PIPE) as proc:
    for line in proc.stdout:
        # printing as a replacement for my processing function
        print(line, end="")
```

Running the above python script on a small directory with a few hundred CSV files prints out nothing.

Running `find /path/to/dir/ -name "*.csv" | wc -l` prints 637 results very quickly.

Am I missing a component in my Popen call?

Comment: I think you probably don't want the single quotes - they would be used in a shell to prevent wildcard expansion in the shell (so that the `*` is passed to `find`) but the quotes themselves should not be passed to `find` unless you actually want to find files that have the `'` in the filename. It should work with `"find . -name *.csv".split()`. Contrast with `"find . -name '*.csv'", shell=True`

Comment: I think you need to replace the `.`  with `/path/to/dir/` since I guess you don't necessarily run your script from the wanted directory

Comment: @alaniwi, yes, this fixed my issue! Thank you!